# UltiSnipsExpandTrigger doesn't work

Tags: vim, macvim

I have the following configuration in my .vimrc file:

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<C-k>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<Down>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<Up>"
```

However for some reason it doesn't expand the snippets.

Does anybody know what seems to be the problem?

Comment: If you have YouCompleteMe, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896327/ultisnips-and-youcompleteme Some answers may help you even if you don't have ycm

Comment: `:verbose imap <C-k>` and check whether its got mapped to ultisnip's expansion or not !

Comment: @dNitro [Here is what I get](https://imagebin.ca/v/2z24zsu3jd0I) when I run the command. It looks like it worked. Does it matter that I run this command on a Mac?

Comment: @flashburn No, actually this command checks whether `<C-k>` is mapped to anything in *insert* mode or not, and it works. The problem may be with your snippets itself. Where you insert your snippets and how you define them ?!!!

Comment: @dNitro I'm not sure if it is a bug or maybe I define a snippet in a wrong way. [Here is what I have for a snippet](http://pastebin.com/ywNCrxds). I start typing in the following way `#inc` which shows me a snippet, but when I select it vim inserts `##inc<` into the code which won't expand.

Comment: @flashburn your snippet definition is also correct and expands as expected.   define your snippet like this: http://pastebin.com/2dWcPtsZ

Comment: @dNitro Do you mean that my definition is incorrect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126159/discussion-between-dnitro-and-flashburn).