# vim 8, UltiSnips and coc-ultisnips: `${VISUAL}` does nothing

Tags: vim, ultisnips, coc.nvim

Using vim 8, Ultisnips, and coc-ultisnips.

Consider this snippet:

```
snippet cdeg "Add console.debug({})"
console.debug(${0:${VISUAL:value}})
endsnippet
```

I would expect it to expand `cdeg` to `console.debug(value)`.

The problem is if I have that buffer:

```
hello
```

Then visual select `hello`, press `C` to replace it with `cdeg` and then expand. I would expect the buffer to look like that:

```
console.debug(hello)
```

But instead, I get

```
console.debug(value)
```

So it would seem `${VISUAL}` has no effect with `coc-ultisnips`. Any idea what is going on, and how to have `coc-ultisnips` behave like UltiSnips regarding `${VISUAL}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that I was using it wrong. In UltiSnips, you have to visual select, then press , then your snippet, then  again. Only then do you get your visual selection inserted.

I don't know if this works with `coc-ultisnips`, because I have switched back to YouCompleteMe + UltiSnips and Supertab: YCM provides better completion results for TypeScript and works fine with UltiSnips.

This is the ticket to using <kbd>Tab</kbd> for YCM and UltiSnips together: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22253548/10421344