# how to move the cursor after the abbrev

Tags: vim

how to move the cursor after the abbrev?

function to remove a space after typing ctor:

> function! Eatchar(pat)
> let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
> return (c=~ a:pat)?'':c
> endfunction

prototype of the class

> autocmd FileType cpp :iabbrev ctor class Noname {<CR>private:<CR><CR>public:<CR>Noname();<CR>~Noname(); <esc>5kb<esc>:.,+5s/Noname/<c-r>=Eatchar('\s')<cr>

**input**: ctor

**output**:

```
class Noname {
private:

public:
Noname();
~Noname();
};
```

*in comand-line: prompt to enter a new class name.*

After entering a new name,

**I would like to move to line #3 (after private:)**

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the limit of abbreviations *and* one-liners, here. I would seriously consider using a snippet expansion plugin like [SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate), [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), or [MiniSnip](https://github.com/Jorengarenar/miniSnip) if I were you.

Here is the snippet in SnipMate:

```
snippet ctor
    class ${1:Noname} {
        private:
        ${2}
        public:
        $1();
        ~$1();
    };
```

and here is how it would look in action:

[image: ctor]

Comment: Thank you very much. But how did you get to the label ${2}?

Comment: I pressed `<Tab>`.

Comment: Strange, I tried to replace  let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>" replace <tab> with <space> or <c-q> or <leader><tab>.   nothing worked ( ps I use YouCompleteMe and UltiSnips)

Comment: I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896327/ultisnips-and-youcompleteme plugin 'ervandew/supertab' thank you so much for your help